# Do any RSS apps available for OS X and/or iOS sync via anything other than Google Reader?

Tags: macos, ios, rss, google

I recently switched from NetNewsWire to Reeder on my iPhone and iPad because a) Reeder as a “Mark as unread” button, and b) I thought NetNewsWire was marking older articles as read, and not letting me switch them back.

I soon realised that old articles were being actually marked as read because Google Reader does that after a month.

Whilst I prefer Reeder’s UI, I think it’s (currently) purely a Google Reader front-end. Are there any RSS apps that sync via some service, free or paid, other than Google Reader, and thus let me keep articles as unread for more than a month?

NetNewsWire used to sync via NewsGator, but I believe NewsGator no longer offer an RSS sync service.

Comment: I don't really want to defend g reader's nonsensical behavior, but I would seriously consider *news* article older than a month old enough to not be news anymore. If it were 1 year I'm sure every one who isn't a monk would agree with me.

Comment: @Cawas: sure, I’m not necessarily saying Google Reader’s wrong or rubbish here (it’s a free service after all), just that it doesn’t fit my usage pattern well. Just because something’s on RSS doesn’t mean it’s *news* though.

Comment: What I mean is that there are other ways to read news and keep updated. Have you tried, for instance, [readitlater](http://readitlaterlist.com/)?

Comment: @Cawas: I’ve not (I’m on Instapaper), but my use case for my RSS reader is: “Show me every new thing posted on this set of websites, and let me mark it as read once I’ve read it.” I assumed readitlater, like Instapaper, doesn’t do that.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. It looks like Instapaper is basically the same thing. And I see where your urge from doing that comes from. I've tried doing the same with RSS readers, including google's, but I could never keep on. One day was enough for late news and way too much crap. I assume if you have a good list of RSS it might work, but I decided to just reach for other means. When I want to read news, I google for them, read around anywhere. And I get some feeds on email. That's about it. So, I keep my vote up (not like I could easily remove it anyway) and my wish to you for good luck! :P

Comment: @Cawas: oh yeah, it only works because I tend to read sites that either post little links to other sites where I can quickly decide if I want to read it or not, or that post reasonably infrequent longer articles that I always want to read. (Daring Fireball is the prime example of this.) If I don’t want to read most of what a site publishes, I don’t subscribe to it. RSS isn’t about news for me, it’s about things I’m interested in.

Comment: Paul, one more reason for you to consider my answer! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the absence of answers (aside from Cawas’ sterling efforts), I’m going to call this one a “no” for now. The situation *might just* change once iOS 5 and iCloud go live.

Answer (score 0):

My last comment just gave me one idea that might solve your issue: [Google's Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/home). You can [configure it to send emails from any feed](http://www.google.com/search?q=setup+feedburner+e-mail+subscription). It will be little troublesome at first as it's a long manual job. Seems like it is unsupported and not really meant to be used like this. But it works perfectly!

Here are some [quotes from its own help](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78982):

> ### What triggers the email to be sent out?
>
> FeedBurner sends subscribers a daily
>   digest of new content from your blog,
>   so a new post, new title, link, or
>   change to the published date will
>   trigger the email delivery. If you do
>   not post anything that day, no email
>   is sent out.
>
> FeedBurner only keeps a change history
>   for items currently listed in the
>   feed. Once they “drop off the bottom”
>   of the feed, the system forgets about
>   them completely. If you re-introduced
>   them later by increasing the number of
>   items your feed contains, this will
>   result in the newly included items
>   being delivered via email as “new”
>   content.
>
> ### How much does this service cost and what methods of payment are accepted?
>
> FeedBurner Email is a free service.
>   However, we do accept voluntary
>   payment in the form of props and
>   general goodwill.
>
> ### How do you get started?
>
> Sign in to your FeedBurner account,
>   select your feed, navigate to the
>   Publicize tab and select "Email
>   Subscriptions."