# How do I transfer my RSS feeds from Safari, now that it no longer supports RSS?

Tags: safari, macos, rss

I have hundreds of RSS feeds saved as bookmarks in Safari, but the latest version (6.0) has disabled RSS feeds, and suggests getting a dedicated RSS reader from the App Store:

[image]

Is there a simple general procedure for transferring all of my saved RSS feeds from Safari to a new reader?

Comment: It appears that this question [may boil down](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10532/4395) to finding a way to transfer feeds from Safari to Google Reader.

Comment: Do you also need archived *content* to be transfered? (I do, but from Mail.app, for which the archives are still in `~/Library/Mail/RSS`, but that's a different question.)

Comment: @Arjan: No such folder for me, so I guess not.

Comment: Well, the folder was for RSS in Mail. But I assume that does not change your requirements.

Comment: If you're Google searching, you want something that can export to OPML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing an RSS reader, any attempt to open one of your existing feeds in Safari should open the RSS reader. For most readers, (e.g. [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/mac/index)) this will cause the app to ask if you want to subscribe to the just-opened feed. Once you've done that for a feed, you can delete it from Safari.